# Как проверить, существует ли определенная ячейка массива?

Tags: java

Изначальные данные:

Есть arrayList,
заранее неизвестно существует ли искомая ячейка массива.

Я не знаю, как сделать условие по типу
 ( если arr(1) не существует),
{ то создать}

Можно сделать, через ловлю исключений, но я сомневаюсь, что подобное даже близко можно назвать оптимальным решением

```java
                      try{
                        arr.get(count);
                    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){

                        System.out.println("исключение");
                        arr.add(count, "значение");
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (count >= 0 && count < arr.size())
  arr.get(count);
else
  ... sozdat'
```

Comment: Это гениально! Огромное Вам спасибо.

Comment: @i'mNasten'ka Ну что Вы! Не стoит... :)